# How to write unit test for spring cloud stream function based method?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder

When I try to test a spring cloud stream function based method, it always happens NullPointerException about InputDestination.

I have two questions:

1. It's hard for me to know how to write UT from the official doc. [official test doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing)
2. Besides, how to write integration Test if test file has some dependencies. It seems create a new context and always has NoSuchBeanDefination error.

I have tried as flow, but the context can not find some dependency beans.

```java
@Test
public void sampleTest() {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(
                TestChannelBinderConfiguration.getCompleteConfiguration(
                        MyTestConfiguration.class))
                .run("--spring.cloud.function.definition=uppercase")) {
        InputDestination source = context.getBean(InputDestination.class);
        OutputDestination target = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);
        source.send(new GenericMessage<byte[]>("hello".getBytes()));
        assertThat(target.receive().getPayload()).isEqualTo("HELLO".getBytes());
    }
}
```

So I just want to write UT, but still have NPE.

Here is my code.

```java
    @Bean
    public Function<Message<List<DemoBean>>, Message<DemoBean>> findFirstBean( ){
        return message -> {
            List<DemoBean> demoBeans =  message.getPayload();
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(demoBeans.get( 0 )).build();
        };
    }
```

Here is my test.

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    @ActiveProfiles(profiles = "local")
    @Import({ TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class})
    class FunctionDemoTest {

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination inputDestination;
    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination outputDestination;
    private FunctionDemo functionDemo;
    // some dependency need to mock
    private DemoService demoService;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        demoService = Mockito.mock( DemoService.class );
        functionDemo = new FunctionDemo( demoService);
    }


    @Test
    public void findFirstBeanTest() {
        DemoBean demoBean = new DemoBean();
        demoBean.setName("Howard");
        demoBean.setAge( 1 );
        DemoBean demoBean1 = new DemoBean();
        demoBean1.setName("Frank");
        demoBean1.setAge( 2 );
        List<DemoBean> demoBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
        demoBeanList.add( demoBean );
        demoBeanList.add( demoBean1 );

        Message<List<DemoBean>> inputMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(demoBeanList).build();
        inputDestination.send(inputMessage,"findFirstBean-in-0");
        
        Assertions.assertNotNull(  outputDestination.receive( 10000, "findFirstBean-out-0") );

    }


    }
```

Here is error:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel.send(org.springframework.messaging.Message) of a null object returned from org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination.getChannelByName(java.lang.String)

    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.InputDestination.send(InputDestination.java:89)
    at com.successfactors.caf.listener.FunctionDemoTest.raePdrResultProcessor(FunctionDemoTest.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know the root cause of NPE.

```java
Message<byte[]> receive(long timeout, String bindingName)
```

It seems should be destinationName instead of bindingName in source code.

Any other answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it should be destination name since test binder emulates an interaction with a real messaging system to ensure that the message gets a chance to go thru the same process as with real binder. So the Input/Output destination effectively emulate queues, topics etc of real messaging systems. These destination are bound to user code via abstraction called bindings. But yes you send/receive to/from destinations, not bindings

Comment: Yes, but the param name in source code is not appropriate. It may lead confusion.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean `public void send(Message<?> message, String destinationName)`. Also, the javadoc states `Allows the {@link Message} to be sent to a Binder's destination.. . .` and then there is even clarification. What else do you think is missing?

Comment: I mean the variable name is not correct in source code. It seems should be destinationName instead of bindingName when calling `Message<byte[]> receive(long timeout, String bindingName)`.

Comment: the NPE is because of function properties name?! are you series!!!